# How to reference foreign key in mysql at phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using mysql in phpmyadmin. I have created two tables.

```
company (
company_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
company_name VARCHAR(20) 
);

users (
user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
user_first_name VARCHAR(20) ,
user_last_name VARCHAR(20),
user_type VARCHAR(10),
user_email VARCHAR(40)
);
```

Now i want to declare Foreign key company(company) reference to users(user_id). SO company will be primary and foreign key at same time. How do i Do that?

Comment: Remember, names can be a *lot* longer than 20 characters and email addresses are frequently > 40 characters. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default unless you have a very compelling reason to use something shorter.

Comment: Something can be a primary key of its own table and a foreign key of another. That's actually pretty normal.

Comment: Thank you @tadman for your input. But how do i reference foreign key in phpmyadmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a database client, it's not a database, so try and avoid confusion between that tool and MySQL itself. This is all covered in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). If you can connect directly to the database you might find the [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) client to be significantly better.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to add the following to the `users` table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (company) REFERENCES company(company_id)
```

Which will create a new key in that table called `company`, which references the `company_id` of the `company` table.

Comment: I went to relation view and did this 
    ALTER TABLE `company` ADD CONSTRAINT `company_id_fk` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES 
    `company`(`company_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE 
    RESTRICT;

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `company` ADD CONSTRAINT `company_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`user_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;